# Why does angular differentiate between `<my-element></my-element>` and `<my-element />`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just discovered a weird issue with Angular 1.2.1, demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0m04gat/) (tested in both IE, FF, and Chrome): if I create a very simple templated directive, it fails to work as `<my-element />` if it hasn't first been used as `<my-element></my-element>`.

This is the js code from the fiddle in its entirety:

```
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').directive('myElement', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<p>Hello, element!</p>'
    };
});
```

and the html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <my-element />
    <my-element></my-element>
</div>
```

The output I expect from that is two paragraphs with the contents `Hello, element!`, but I only get one. If, however, I reverse the order of the two `<my-element>`-tags, so that the self-closing one comes after, both of them give output.

Why does Angular behave in this pathological way?

Comment: Self-closing tags don't exist in HTML5, that's invalid markup you got there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your own self-closed tag should not be used

The browser interprets if a tag is "self-closeable" or not.

It doesn't know your tag as "self-closeable" (he knows only the HTML tags) and this is why it has a strange behavior.

On [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#content-model) you can find the Elements section:

> A **void element** is an element whose content model **never allows** it to have **contents** under any circumstances.
>
> The following is a **complete list of the void elements** in HTML:
> **area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr**
>
> A **non-void element must have an end tag**, unless the subsection for that element in the HTML elements section of this reference indicates that its end tag can be omitted....

So, the conclusion is: don't use the short form for your own tag.

## Interpreting your own self-closed tag in browser

That strange behavior appears because the browser interprets a **self-closed tag** like a **parent of all siblings** that come **after it**.

Let's ignore the AngularJS for the moment, and let's consider 3 new tags that are not in HTML: `<x>`, `<y>` and `<z>`.

E.g.:

```
<x></x>
<y></y>
<z></z>
```

will appear in the source code (<kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome) as they are.

But

```
<x></x>
<y/>
<z></z>
```

will look like:

```
<x></x>
<y>
    <z></z>
</y>
```

Now, they we have this information, let's come back to AngularJS:

```
<my-element />
<my-element></my-element>
```

becomes

```
<my-element>
    <my-element></my-element>
</my-element>
```

and the "main" = parent `<my-element>` is found and replaced by `<p>Hello, element!</p>`. => one output line => in this case you can also have some text or other tags after the 2nd line of code, because they will be wrapped in the parent and the result will be the same.

But, on the other hand:

```
<my-element></my-element>
<my-element />
```

will become

```
<my-element></my-element>
<my-element></my-element>
```

that will be displayed 2 times.

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with the browser "learning tags".

Answer (score 2):

Here is the issue :-

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1237

In HTML there is no such thing as a self closing tag. There are only tags which are leafs. Leaf tags are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to earlier answers, this will give a better idea on what's happening. Run this in jsfiddle.

The self closing tag is assumed to be the starting tag and all the text following is thought of as directive's content.

```js
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
    .directive('myElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<p>Hello, <span ng-transclude></span> element!</p>'
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <my-element/>
    <my-element>jfdsfkl</my-element>
    <my-element>jfdsfkl</my-element>
    
    <my-element/>    
    <my-element>jfdsfkl</my-element>    
</div>
```